Регулярки для Excel / LibreOffice
Есть табличный файл:

Таких табличек много, как удалить пустые строки в объединённых ячейках? Я пробовал прогонять регулярки, выданные ИИ, но ничего не сработало

Удалить пустые строки в Excel можно только с помощью VBA. Если вам интересно это решение, то я могу помочь.

@rotabor да, интересно, если у Вас есть время и желание. Свою задачу я решил - найти и заменить "\n\n", этого оказалось достаточно....

Похоже, я не совсем верно понял ваш вопрос.

В общем решение оказалось очень простое - Найти и заменить "\n\n"

В общем, ЕИ (ПИ, ЧИ) победил ИИ. :-)

@rotabor скорее победила интуиция, особенно распалённая в условиях крайне-важной степени задачи))
